# Alias name for nested resources rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested-routes

I have batch_class model, and under that articles, assignments resources are there. The routes.rb look like this.

```
resources :batch_classes do
  member do 
    resources :articles, except: [:index] 
    resources :assignments
 end
```

end

The problem is I am not getting desired URL route. 
My `rake routes` for edit `assignments` shows this.

```
/batch_classes/:id/assignments/:id/edit(.:format)
```

with alias name of edit_assignment_path. However, my expected route is

```
/batch_classes/:batch_class_id/assignments/:id/edit(.:format).
```

Please help.

Comment: Take `resources :assignments` out of member block and do check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired path route can be achieved by taking `resources :assignments` out of the member block.

```
resources :batch_classes do
  resources :assignments
  member do 
    #...
  end
end
```

Going through [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) document is highly recommended for correct implementation.

Comment: I was following this documentation, i am afraid they have put wrong info here. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.2/routing.html#nested-resources    check the tables under nested-resources section. they have used same `:id` twice in edit route.

Comment: It has been fixed now.

Comment: The issue is not there in the current version of doc but 3.2.2.

Answer (score 3):

You can have nested routes by just putting nested resource inside parent resources.

```
resources :batch_classes do
  resources :assignments
end
```

Then, you surely will have a route called `edit_batch_class_assignment_path` and 
you can pass in instances as `edit_batch_class_assignment_path(@batch_class, @assignment)`